# My deployed page on github is going to another page which does not exist

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, github-pages

I am learning React and I have completed a project and deployed it using GitHub page. But when its deployed, its pointing to **textutils--React** but I have no such page it should be pointing to the home page. And when I click the home page or about page in the website, it works fine.
I want the deployed page to take me to the home page directly when opening my project using GitHub page.

[image: GitHub page]

```
Link - <https://github.com/shresthgour/textutils--React>  
Website Link on GitHub - <https://shresthgour.github.io/textutils--React/>  
Correct Link - <https://shresthgour.github.io/>
```

Comment: Sorry for adding the links that way it was not accepting the links and it was treating them as code

Comment: The link is correct. If you want the other one you have to name your repo `shresthgour.github.io`

Comment: if you click on that link it will take you to some other page instead of the home page

Answer (score 0):

Your link is not wrong, it is behaving exactly like it was designed by GitHub.
If you create a repository and deploy with GitHub pages the root address will be: `{userName}.github.io/{repositoryName}/`, which in your case is: `shresthgour.github.io/textutils--React/`.
GitHub also lets you have a root repository. To achieve this you have to use a specific repository name, that woudl be: `{userName}.github.io` and then GitHub will serve your website at that address.
So in your case you can create a repositoty named `shresthgour.github.io`. Then copy the repostory `textutils--React` to `shresthgour.github.io`, deploy the same way you deployed and then you will be able to see your website at [shresthgour.github.io](https://shresthgour.github.io).